# Mootools extends the "Function" class with an "extend" method making jQuery unusable

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, mootools, mozilla

Mootools extends the "Function" class and adds a new method called "extend" in it. Now jQuery tries to add "extend" function using jQuery.prototype.extend. However since "extend" is already a part of the jQuery object (since jQuery is an object of the Function class) so jQuery.prototype.extend doesn't work.
Did anyone come across this conflict while using Mootools and jQuery simultaneously ?

More generically, if a native class like "Function or Array or Object" is extended, do we have a way to revert back to the original definitions ?

Comment: why would you care about the prototype chain if you are defining it locally - it will/ should not go to Function.prototype.extend if it sees jQuery.prototype.extend within that scope... https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L313 they don't seem to check the prototype chain for function

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L68 jQuery.fn is actually defined to be equal to jQuery.prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // copy the original function
    var ext = Function.prototype.extend;
    // remove it
    delete Function.prototype.extend;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Copy the jQuery version
    var jqext = jQuery.prototype.extend;
    // remove it (for sanity).
    delete jQuery.prototype.extend;

    // reassign the original function.
    Function.prototype.extend = ext;
    // remove the jQuery extend method (now the original Function.extend method)
    delete jQuery.prototype.extend;
    // reassign jQuery's original extend method.
    jQuery.prototype.extend = jqext;
</script>
```

Comment: The solution works fine. However I didn't get why we do a delete jQuery.prototype.extend (for sanity one) and then once again after reassinging function.prototype.extend. Does changing the baseclass also change the already inherited classes ?

Comment: I removed it because I didn't like the idea of needing to compensate for what might happen if `Function.prototype.extend = ext;` messed with it.  I've found that assigning to an empty variable name has less potential to need to be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQery.noConflict ? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Yes I have. noConflict helps avoid conflict with the "$" . However here its not about variable naming. Its about an extended base class.